Joomla 5: Error 0 Object of class Joomla\CMS\Image\Image could not be converted to string
I am trying to use the Joomla image class (use Joomla\CMS\Image\Image) in a com_fields field layout override.
$image = new Image($image);

gives me the following error message:
0 Object of class Joomla\CMS\Image\Image could not be converted to string
The image path is correct, as the following message appears when this is changed
0 The image file does not exist.
Is this a Joomla core bug or is something else missing?

You already have a property defined called $image that you are passing into the creation of a new Image object that is also called $image. I would assume the first definition of $image is a type of string and you are trying to update it with a type of object, hence the attempt to convert it to a string.
I think you need to change one of the $image properties to something else avoid the conflict.
$image_obj = new Image($image);


Thanks a lot. This took me the whole weekend, since it has been changed since Joomla 3 ;-)
